# what does "open box guys"/ "sealed guys" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "There are people who just like to buy opened VHS tapes, and they don't think there can be sealed VHS tapes at the moment"?

"There's people who are only open box guys, and they're very skeptical of sealed guys and what it means to their own collecting", Carlson said. "But I just think it's a good thing. It's just a difference in the way that you're collecting."

Source: https://www.ibtimes.com/back-dead-vhs-tapes-trigger-new-collecting-frenzy-3566324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard either phrase before (they're not idioms in general English), but they seem to mean "collectors who are only interested in items that have been used, so the box has been opened" and "collectors who are only interested in items that have never been used, so the box is still sealed".

Answer (score 2):

In English, it is common when explaining something to someone about types of people who do this or that or who like this or that, to use a word to refer to those people. **guy** is just one word for to refer to them. He could have said people or guys or collectors to mean the same thing.

The author of this post [?] could have as easily said: **open box or sealed box people.**

> Here is an example of a VHS tape that is still in the shrink wrapped
> box:
>
> A sealed VHS copy of 1980’s time-travel classic Back To The Future has
> sold at auction for $75,000 USD.
>
> The video tape – that belonged to Biff Tannen actor Tom Wilson – was
> the star lot at an auction of 260 sealed VHS tapes at Heritage
> Auctions in Texas.
>
> The shrink wrapped tape from 1986 was graded and described as being in
> near mint condition and the sum paid for it is thought to be the
> highest ever for a VHS tape.
>
> Wilson consigned sealed copies of all three films in the trilogy with
> Back to the Future II selling for $16,250 USD and Back to the Future
> III achieving $13,750 USD. Both were accompanied with signed
> provenance from late MCA executive VP and Universal Pictures chairman
> Tom Pollock.
>
> His 1990 Trilogy Box Set also sold for $10,000 USD.

[sealed box set](https://hypebeast.com/2022/6/sealed-vhs-copy-back-to-the-future-auction-75000usd-bttf-video)

Sealed VHS tapes of famous movies can be worth a lot of money! :)

[image: Back to the Future]

Unfortunately, you can't see the shrink wrap. At least, I can't.